# Python Dask: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I am trying to capture a very large structured table from a postregres table. It has approximately: 200,000,000 records. I am using `dask` instead of pandas, because it is faster. When I am loading the data into `df` it is significantly faster than pandas.

I am trying to convert dask DataFrame into Pandas dataframe using `compute`, it keeps giving me ValueError NA/inf. 
I have passed dtype='object', but it is not working. Any way to fix it?

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('mytable1', 
                       index_col='mytable_id', schema='books',
                       uri='postgresql://myusername:mypassword@my-address-here12345678.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:12345/BigDatabaseName')


pandas_df = df.compute(dtype='object')
```

Gives error: 
`ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: You're saying it's faster but dask isn't loading the data until you call compute.

Comment: @postelrich. I can see the columns in dask `df` though. It shows: Dask DataFrame Structure

Comment: you mean if you print? dask gets the head/tail for repr.

Comment: Any progress at this? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that one of your columns has nulls but dask inferred it as an integer. Dask looks at a sample of the data to infer dtypes so may not pick up sporadic nulls. Before you call compute you can inspect the dtypes and convert the column type using `astype` to `object` for the column you think may be the issue.

Comment: `pandas_df = df.compute(dtype={'column1':'object','column2':'object'})`. I tried this as well, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for unknown column types!

```
my_cols = ['a', 'b',...]
meta_dict = dict(zip(my_cols, [object]*len(my_cols)))
ddf = dd.read_sql_table(..., meta=meta_dict, ....)
df = ddf.compute()
df['a_int'] = df['a'].astype('int64', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, Post making changes as suggested, i am getting below error.

 in _read_sql_chunk
    elif len(meta.dtypes.to_dict()) == 0:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtypes'

Comment: @Raj Perhaps working with `len(meta.dtypes.to_dict())` could be changed to `len(meta)`