# IntCastingNaNError when calling .compute()

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have dask bag with 59 n_partitions with chucksize of 100 000 ( so basically around 6 million records). I want to transform dask bag to dask dataframe and then to pandas dataframe. This is my snippet.

```
%%time
bag = dask_mongo.read_mongo(
    database="XXXXX",
    collection="XXXX",
    connection_kwargs={"XXXXXXXX"},
    chunksize=100000,
)
df = bag.to_dataframe()
df = df.astype('object')
df2 = df.compute()
```

I tried multiple things - cast every column to dtype object, remove na values with dropna(). Everytime i get this exception:

```
IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I understand that it needs to get rid of NaN objects, but i tried multiple ways and no success.

Compute to list

```
list = bag.compute()
```

works fust fine.

I even tried to take one column and cast it o float64 (as i read, pandas do not support NaN in integer data types, so a tried float64 and object dtype) :

```
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=59
    float64
        ...
     ...   
        ...
        ...
Name: xxx, dtype: float64
Dask Name: astype, 236 tasks
```

but even there i get **IntCastingNaNError** ..

But i really want it in dataframe so i can do analysis on those data later on. Thanks..

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60308435/8443371 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for unknown column types!

```
my_cols = ['a', 'b',...]
meta_dict = dict(zip(my_cols, [object]*len(my_cols)))
ddf = bag.to_dataframe(meta=meta_dict)
df = ddf.compute()
df['a_int'] = df['a'].astype('int64', errors='ignore')
```